# React Native - undefined is not an object while trying to pass parameters

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make a user registration screen for my app.

My screen consists in 2 textinputs and a button, when pressed, the button triggers a function, to which I pass the content of the 2 inputs, and fetch a PHP script to register those ids in my database:

```
class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      UserName: '',
      UserEmail: ''
    }
  }

  UserRegistrationFunction () {
    const { UserName } = this.state
    const { UserEmail } = this.state

    fetch('[the address with my .php]', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: UserName,
        email: UserEmail
      })

    }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        Alert.alert(responseJson)
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
      })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, color: '#000', textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: 15 }}>User Registration Form</Text>
        <TextInput
          placeholder='Entrez votre nom'
          onChangeText={UserName => this.setState({UserName})}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder='Entrez votre E-mail'
          onChangeText={UserEmail => this.setState({UserEmail})}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
        />
        <Button title="M'enregistrer" onPress={this.UserRegistrationFunction} color='#2196F3' />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error "undefined is not an object (evaluating this.state.UserName)" when the button is pressed, but it seems I did everything the right way.

Comment: You need to bind `this` or use arrow functions. [more info](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: i already tried this, but it returns a "JSON parse error: Unable to parse JSON string"

Comment: Thats realated to line `response.json()`. The response from the server has invalid char inside so it can not parse.

Comment: oh ok, i didn't realise the 2 problems weren't related, i thought the JSON error was on the stringify ...
Would you know if my way of sending back a response 

"$RetryMSG = 'Réessayez' ;
    $RetryJson = json_encode($RetryMSG);
    echo $RetryJson ;"


Is right ?

Anyway, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

this line removes the username from the state:

```
onChangeText={UserEmail => this.setState({UserEmail})}
```

change the setState to

```
this.setState({...this.state, UserEmail})
```

it will work for you Or you can use an arrow function for setting the state